# Создать массив годов в диапазон от 18 до 100 лет

Tags: javascript

Как создать массив годов в диапазон от 18 до 100 лет, который расчитывается так: первый элемент массива **текущий год - 100 лет**, последний элемент **текущий год - 18 лет**

Comment: При помощи цикла )

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задание тогда так:

```js
function createArrayYers(currentYer){
  const start = currentYer - 100;
  const end = currentYer - 18;
  const arr = [];
  
  for (let i = start; i <= end; ++i){
    arr.push(i);
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(createArrayYers(2022));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я в своем проекте на typescript реализовал такой генератор массивов:

```
const generateArray = (count:number, builder: (index:number) => any) => {
    return Array.apply(undefined, Array(count)).map((e, i) => builder(i));
}
```

Первый параметр `count:number` - это количество элементов, которые нужно сгенерировать. Второй параметр `builder`, который имеет тип `(index:number) => any`, то есть, функция, принимающая параметром число - индекс нынешней итерации и возвращает значение с любым типом.

Использовать вот так, например, нагенерировать массив с числами от 1 до 100:

```
const numbers= generateArray(99, (i) => i+1);
```

Далее, уже для своих условий используйте такой генератор.